# iOS - use of @import when modules are disabled error

Tags: ios, ios8, cocoapods

I am receiving this error when using the DCPathButton library (through podspec).

Modules are enabled in my project settings. Do i need to do anything else to enable modules in pods?

Comment: Same problem here. did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

If "Link Frameworks Automatically" is already set to YES in the Build Settings, you have to set "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" as well.

Comment: I have both Link Frameworks Automatically and Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) set to yes, but don't work for me, the error remains

Comment: The cause is that I'm using Objective-C++. Then modules in this case get disabled despite the proper build settings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701647/use-of-import-when-modules-are-disabled

Comment: I had to [also enable the `-fcxx-modules` compiler flag as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481558/111307)

Answer (score 2):

Set the "Link Frameworks Automatically" to YES