# use of @import when modules are disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, import, module

I have the following import in my code:

```
@import Foundation;
```

I am encountering the following build error:

```
use of @import when modules are disabled
```

I have seen [@import vs #import - iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7) and I have set "Enable Modules" to "YES".

Despite this, my problem is not solved.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Your question is surely your answer? I thought that you had to enable modules to be able to use @import?

Comment: **Unfortunately `@import` is [not supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921045/8740349) for `.mm` files or rather `Objective-C++`** (I tested with both `g++` and `clang++` as I really wanted to make this work).

Answer (score 106):

I got this warning in a zero-swift project whenever I tried to add the `@import SafariServices;` statement.

Solution:
**Enable the modules.** Go to the Target > Build Settings and set the Enable Modules (C and Objective-C modules) to **YES**.

[image: I've circled the Build Settings toggle to change.]

**OR**

*Note: I haven't verified this potential solution, but probably worthy of consideration if there are side effects caused by this solution.*

> Rather than enabling modules to entire project, we can enable modules for a specific file which is importing c++ file. Go to build phases -> Compile Sources -> Select the file -> Add compiler flag `-fmodules`

Comment: Thanks! worked for me. PS: you forgot to censor your target name :-)

Comment: Thanks @Josh , much appreciated.

Comment: To my amazement, this didn't resolve the matter for me. Then after running out of ideas as I was sure THIS IS right, I restarted Xcode (9.2) and then it worked totally fine. Sigh.

Comment: Xcode 9.3, struggled with same, did same, and happened to read your note Mr. Snell, quit Xcode and opened, and THAT completed the solution. (bad Xcode dog BAD :-)

Comment: Thanks Peter - I've been trying to update parse and parse/ui on an old app to move it to sashido and i was banging my head agains the wall that none of the PF stuff was working!

Answer (score 43):

The possible cause is that you use Objective-C++. Then modules get disabled despite the proper build settings.

Comment: I, at one point had .mm files in the project.  They are no longer there.  I double checked - no .mm files in project.   Also, i have done everything already described in this thread.  Still getting the same error.  Modules are enabled on all targets. Foundation is imported.   I checked the file types on all source files, they are Objective-C, not Objective-C++.    Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed the issue is caused by importing the framework (with @import Foundation) into a .mm file

Comment: I am using Obj-C++, and facing this same problem. What should I do?

Comment: you should create an Obj-C wrapper that use @import (if you actually need to)

Comment: hundred times this! i removed `@import Foundation` from MyFramework.h and it works now!

Answer (score 28):

I've been mixing ObjC, ObjC++, C++, and Metal. Whenever I get the "use of @import when modules are disabled" I try
replacing:

```
@import Name;
```

with:

```
#import "Name/Name.h"
```

example, replace:

```
@import Metal;
@import MetalKit;
@import CoreVideo;
```

with:

```
#import "Metal/Metal.h"
#import "MetalKit/MetalKit.h"
#import "CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h"
```

It seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me too by replacing `@import GoogleMobileAds;` with `#import "GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView.h"`

Answer (score 14):

Check if you are using `#import "ProductName-Swift.h"` somewhere in .mm files or any other files other than objc files.

Because if you use this import in cpp files then modules gets disabled automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using objective-c++ (.mm file) and none of solutions above work, you can try the following:

- Open Xcode Build Settings
- Targets -> Build Settings -> Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags > Other C++ Flags
- Add `-fcxx-modules` flag

then build again. The error should be gone.

Credit: https://developers.karte.io/docs/setup-react-native-sdk-v2