# use of '@import' when c++ modules are disabled, consider using -fmodules and -fcxx-modules

Tags: admob, objective-c++

This came up for me when I tried to integrate AdMob using Cocoapods into an Objective C++ project.

> use of '@import' when c++ modules are disabled, consider using -fmodules and -fcxx-modules

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Fix is [easy](https://github.com/infobip/mobile-messaging-sdk-ios/issues/6#issuecomment-327881752), you have to do what the warning says and not only [enable C and Objective-C modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667236/111307) but also C++ modules.

So you must add the compiler flag `-fcxx-modules` to "Other C++ Flags" in your Build Settings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open **Build Settings** tab under **TARGETS**
2. Search `GCC_INPUT_FILETYPE`
3. Check the value of **Compile Sources**, change the value to **According to File Type** if it's not